# Is Django lying to me?! render_to_response function returns TemplateDoesNotExist when the file does indeed exist

Tags: django, templates, mod-wsgi

OK.  I have read many other accounts of this happening, and they were always solved when the question asker correctly modified their TEMPLATE_DIRS setting.  None of these suggestions have worked for me.  The strange thing is that the template loads when using the Django web server, but errors out when using mod_wsgi.  I think django is maybe throwing an incorrect exception, because the TemplateDoesNotExist error simply can not apply given my settings.

My code:

my app/views/view.py (yes, i have my views in a subfolder)

```
  8 def index(request):
  9     return render_to_response('pages/home/base_home.html')
```

Here is my settings.py located at root (standard location)

```
106 TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
107     # Put strings here, like "/home/html/django_templates" or "C:/www/django/templates".
108     # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
109     # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
110     "/home/foobar/templates",
111 )
```

And finally, here is my view located at /home/foobar/templates/pages/home/

```
  1 {% extends 'base.html' %}
  2 
  3 {% block navigation %}
  4     {% include 'modules/navigation/navigation.html' %}
  5 {% endblock %}
  6 
  7 {% block slideshow %}
  8     {% include 'modules/slideshow/slideshow.html' %}
  9 {% endblock %}
```

Also, here is an ls -l proving that the file does exist

```
foo@bar:~$ ls -l templates/pages/home/
total 12
-rwxr-xr-x 1 foo foo 205 2011-06-05 12:37 base_home.html
foo@bar:~$
```

Here is the postmortem report that Django gives me:

```
Template-loader postmortem

Django tried loading these templates, in this order:
Using loader django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader:
/home/foobar/templates/pages/home/base_home.html (File does not exist)
Using loader django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader:
/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/pages/home/base_home.html (File does not exist)
```

*edit*

Here is my wsgi file

```
  3 import os
  4 import sys
  5 
  6 path = '/media/PENDRIVE/Projects/'
  7 if path not in sys.path:
  8     sys.path.append(path)
  9     
 10 os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'myproject.settings'
 11 
 12 import django.core.handlers.wsgi
 13 application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
 14
```

Thank you for any insight, as I am baffled and stuck!

Answer (score 0):

You should check if the template folder is readable by the user the wsgi process runs with. I suppose this is a simple permission problem.

Comment: Hi.  Thanks for your suggestion.  my permissions are: drwxr-xr-x  9 foo foo    4096 2011-06-05 12:57 templates.  I changed it to be readable to everyone for debugging.  Still does not work.

Comment: The templates folder alone doesn't necessarily make it readable by the wsgi process. If for example /home/foobar is restricted to be readable only by foobar, then this will still not work.

Comment: @mu  Yes, I did.  For testing, I have recursively chmod 755'd the entire project directory, and the templates directory.  Any user can read and execute all files.  Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: Still sounds like permissions, do you have SELinux enabled by any chance?

Comment: I do.  But, the thing that is  getting me is that it does work when using the django webserver.  mod_wsgi is giving me problems.  I will post what I have in that file, since this is my first time using mod_wsgi.  Also, elaborate on the SElinux thing.  What do you think could be a problem?  Also, do you see any issues with my code above?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You're not including the correct url. It should be "pages/home/modules/navigation/navigation.html"

Comment: Hi. Thanks, but this does not solve the problem.  I had already tried replacing the template's content with 'hello world'.  I still get the same error telling me that: /home/foobar/templates/pages/home/base_home.html (File does not exist).  Thank you though!

Answer (score 0):

this should be solved by replacing the full path of BASE_DIR in the settings.py

```
TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': ['/var/www/assistance/templates','templates'],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        ],
    },
},
]
```